# Windows batch file that reads commands from txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have this test.txt file with the following content:

```
@echo off
wget -q http://subs.ro/get/21518
move 21518 %userprofile%/Desktop/21518.zip
%userprofile%/Desktop/21518.zip
```

This file is generated by a javascript and the content keeps changes.
I have the following text.bat file :

```
for /F "eol=; tokens=1* delims=" %%i in ( test.txt ) do %%i
```

the problem is that the link to the
desktop is not recognized because the system variable %userprofile% is not recognized, is pasted as a txt string.
I am using this setup because I want to convert the bat file to a exe and create an invisible application that does everything in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not rename the file to `test.cmd` and run it directly?

The following should work, though:

```
@echo off
for /F "eol=; tokens=1* delims=" %%i in ( test.txt ) do call :run %%i
goto :eof
:run
%*
goto :eof
```

The reason here is that `for` itself doesn't expand environment variables in its variables. Probably the only point in batch where this is the case. So I'm just handing the line to a subroutine (`run`), which does the executing for me.

Comment: it worked, thanks.
I know is the same thing renaming the file to .cmd, just wanted to create an .exe file.

Comment: There are tools out there to create executables from batch files.

Comment: i was searching for answer like this one, didn't know why environment variables not working, thank you

Answer (score 0):

just rename test.txt to test.bat and run it.

Comment: @johannes.. you won by 23 secs!

Comment: even if the @echo off option is enabled the command prompt window still appears, before the archive is opened, if I create a little app that runs in the background the only thing visible to the user is the download button and the application that handles the archives.

Comment: you can run a .bat file without opening a command prompt. See the START command.